# JAVA I miss the connection

Tags: java, file, display

Hei I´m just learning Java, sorry for silly questions but I hope someone wants to help me. I want that if the user selects 1.that it displays all the files in the root folder.

I wrote the main menu and I wrote the code to show the files in the root folder... now I´m stuck. I don't know how to connect the two codes that works how I want it.

I´m thankful if someone can help me out here.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyProgram {
    
    String ename;
    
    
    MyProgram(int empno, String ename, int salary){
        
        this.ename = ename;
            
    }
    public String toString(){
        return ename;
    
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice = -1;
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Virtual Key Program");
            System.out.println("Please select your choise: ");
            System.out.println("1. Display Files in selected folder");
            System.out.println("2. Edit Files");
            System.out.println("0. EXIT Program");
            break;

        
        }while(choice!=0);
        
}
///// How to connect those codes ?

 {
    
    String path = "/Users/lilli/Desktop/coding course/Assessment_final/root folder";
    
    File file = new File(path);
    
    File rootFolder[] = file.listFiles();
    
    Arrays.sort(rootFolder);
    
    for(File e : rootFolder) {
        
        if(e.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File : " + e.getName());
        }
        else if(e.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + e.getName());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not Known :" + e.getName());
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Create another function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the two functions, one for display and the other for edit.
Then in `main` you can use a `switch` construct to manage all the options (1 and 2). Here I tried to code what I wrote above. A suggestion I can give to you is to use methods as much as you can and keep `main` more clear.

I'm also a newbie, by the way, but I hope I helped you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  switch(choice){
    case 1:
      display();
      break;
    case 2:
      edit();
      break;
}

static void display(){
  //code you wrote to display files
}

static void edit(){
  //code you wrote to edit files
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function in class  `displayFiles`, call it in main:

```
import java.io.File;

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;


class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Virtual Key Program");
        System.out.println("Please select your choise: ");
        System.out.println("1. Display Files in selected folder");
        System.out.println("2. Edit Files");
        System.out.println("0. EXIT Program");
        
        // read input from console using scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // read user choice from console
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        
        if(choice == 1) {
            // Function call
            new Solution().displayFiles();;
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            // do something
        }
    }

    public void displayFiles() {

        String path = "/Users/lilli/Desktop/coding course/Assessment_final/root folder";

        File file = new File(path);

        File rootFolder[] = file.listFiles();

        Arrays.sort(rootFolder);

        for (File e : rootFolder) {

            if (e.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File : " + e.getName());
            } else if (e.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory: " + e.getName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Known :" + e.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```